# Passing JSON object to Controller but loose model binding

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to pass a simple JSON object to a controller using MVC3 and JSON. The object gets passed but I loose all the properties. I see all the properties in firebug on the request but am not sure why I am loosing them on the server. Do all the properties of the object need to be set in order for the mapping to work? I am using MVC3 so the binding should be build in. What am I missing?

Class:

```
[Serializable]
public class StoryNote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StoryCardId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual StoryCard StoryCard { get; set; }
}
```

JSON:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#newNote').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var storynote = {
            StoryNote: {                  
                Note: $('#Note').val(),
                StoryCardId: $('#StoryCard_Id').val(),
                CreatedBy: 'Xyz',                }
        };


        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("PostNote")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(storynote),
            dataType: 'json',                
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#previousNotes').append(data.Note + '<br/>' + data.CreatedBy + '<br/><hr/>');
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostNote(StoryNote newStoryNote)
    {

        StoryNote newNote = new StoryNote { Note = newStoryNote.Note, CreatedBy = newStoryNote.CreatedBy, StoryCardId = newStoryNote.StoryCardId, CreateDate = DateTime.Now };
        db.StoryNotes.Add(newStoryNote);

        return Json(newStoryNote, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a name mismatch in your code - parameter is named "StoryNote" in Javascript code and "newStoryNote" in Controller. Those names should be equal. I believe if you change

```
var storynote = {
        StoryNote: {                  
            Note: $('#Note').val(),
            StoryCardId: $('#StoryCard_Id').val(),
            CreatedBy: 'Xyz',                }
    };
```

to

```
var storynote = {
        newStoryNote: {                  
            Note: $('#Note').val(),
            StoryCardId: $('#StoryCard_Id').val(),
            CreatedBy: 'Xyz',                }
    };
```

then your code should work.

Comment: Thank you very much Sergey! That was the problem, always the easy things that slip by and cause headaches.